# Payload bundle identifier mismatch with Xcode at validation step

Tags: xcode, bundle, identifier, payload

I got ios app project from someone (say zzz), which has been uploaded to Apple App Store, but removed from the store later somehow (not quite sure why). I now need work on this project.

First, I created an app named 'yyyyy with me' in iTunesConnect. I had tried to created app with name 'yyyyy' but got error saying yyyyy has been used.

Back to the code I got form zzz, I saw the old bundle id is com.zzz.yyyyy, apparently not mine, so I changed it to mine like com.xxx.yyyyy where xxx is my domain and yyyyy is the app name.

When I finished coding, and want to submit the app, at the validate step, I got error saying:

.....Specifically, value "nnnnnn.com.xxx.yyyyy" for key "application-identifier" is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot, followed by the bundle identifier.
The executable at Payload/yyyyy.app/yyyyy in Payload/yyyyy.app has been signed with identifier "com.xxx.yyyyy" which does not match the bundle identifier 'com.zzz.yyyyy".

I checked the project 'General' tab, and could not find any com.zzz.yyyyy over there, only with mine com.xxx.yyyyy.

What/where is Payload? I hate Apple's code signing, provision stuff!
How/what should I do to solve the problem? Thanks.

BTW, I'm using xcode5. Team is set to none, but when I add my apple account as team, it says my account is already added.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem. After doing all the things you probably did, I finally **restarted Xcode** and that did the trick. Hope that worked for you too.

Comment: oh!!! You'r right. Simple restart XCode did the trick! I recreated provisioning profiles, re-archive app 10 times before found your answer! Great answer, thank you!

Comment: Note: I deleted the derived project data, cleaned the project and the validation still failed until I restarted Xcode.

Comment: Oh God! It wast that! More then 6 hours creating and removing certificates/profiles... Disappointed with Apple..

Comment: Best. Answer. Ever. Says a lot that I referred to SO before even *trying* a restart. ;)

Comment: Agree completely! Best Answer Ever. After struggling for several hours in trying to fix a similar issue, a restart of Xcode solved it.

Comment: Thanks a Lot ! Just restarting the Xcode works for our Project too

Answer (score 1):

Rule #1 of Xcode: always try restarting Xcode first (like its 1999). But if that didnt fix this issue (didn't for us) - make sure you have actually created the new iOS App in iTunesConnect.